# Disable/Enable JS function on toggle click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page I have few tabs and I was asking if its possible to enable disable that function of the tabs with a toggle click.

The tabs code looks like:

```
jQuery('.tabs a').click(function() {

    var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    jQuery('div.tab_content:not(#' + ref + ')').hide();
    jQuery('#' + ref).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

For the toggle I use: http://papermashup.com/demos/ajax-switch/

Sorry if I am not able to post a link. It is a simply iPhone style toggle switch.

Thanks alot

Comment: Is the switch inside the tabs? Do you mean disable all of the tabs or the currently selected one?

Comment: Can you make clear what the problem is here? By the information you provided it's hard to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear enough. I meant disable the tabs function although still show the current function. So its like you wont be able to change tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i understand you meen something like that ?:

```
//global variable you can change it anywhere 
var disable_function = false;


jQuery('.tabs a').click(function() {
    if (!disable_function ){
      var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
      jQuery('div.tab_content:not(#' + ref + ')').hide();
      jQuery('#' + ref).fadeIn();
      return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**

```
var disable_function = false;


jQuery('.tabs a').click(function() {
    if (!disable_function ){
      disable_function = true;
      var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
      jQuery('div.tab_content:not(#' + ref + ')').hide();
      jQuery('#' + ref).fadeIn();
      return false;
    }
});
```

above code will execute this function only once

Comment: Thanks alot. I think its what i am looking for. How do i change the variable to true on click?

Comment: i am not sure what you want to do but you can put it inside click then you will execute given function only once or change it anywhere on the page if you want to disable this function , but i need more details to say more